# Nginx use path as PHP parameter

Tags: nginx

I want to use URL path as URL param
here is what I want to achieve

whenever a user enters `example.com/abc` then the request should automatically redirect to `example.com/?abc` without modifying the URL at the user's end. Currently nginx treating `/abc` as path and throwing 404.

Additionally, existing files should not be redirected, e.g. `example.com/demo.php` should be served as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a rewrite engine... for example like this (in server config):

After some research, this worked for me -

```
location / {
...
   if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    rewrite ^/([^?].*) /?$1 permanent;


}
```

OLD answer -

```
server {
    ...
    if (!-f $request_filename){
       rewrite ^/(.*) /?$1;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but it is redirecting all URLs including existing files. I don't want to redirect files let's say `domain.com/hello.php` should be served as it is. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @PritamPawade edited, also changed a bit regex, so it wouldn't count anything that starts with `?` - that may not be important (as it probably is counted as an argument, not url) but, depending on the rest of the server configuration, it could be

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work

Comment: @PritamPawade what didn't work? does the file exist? Because the if checks if the file exists. Try now.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I made some research myself and this worked for me, updating your answer, so it will help someone in future

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
server {
    root /example/path;
    server_name example.com;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
}
```

This will make first nginx check if a file or directory matching the request URI part exists, and nginx serves it.

If there is no match, then the request is passed to `/index.php` with URI part as query argument.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: Please explain in more details, what exactly you tried, what was the result and what was the expected result.